# Why this small python script is so slow ? Maybe using the wrong lib ? Suggestions?

Tags: python, urllib

I am training python at my high school. We are still learning. 
We did this small script where it loads a website using cookies and downloads files with 400k each. But for some reason, it is very slow. Our internet connection is very fast. It should be able to download 20-30 files at once, but for some reason, it downloads just one file at once and still waits some seconds before download the next. Why is this so? Please, check the script and give suggestions. No matter where we run the script, it always downloads a maximum of 7-8 files per minute. It is not right.

check out:

```
    import urllib.request,string,random
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

ab = 0
faturanum = 20184009433300
while (ab != 1000000):
    try:
        ab = ab + 1
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        a = id_generator() + ".pdf"
        faturanum = faturanum - 1
        fatura = str(faturanum)
        faturanome = fatura + ".pdf"
        opener.addheaders = [('Cookie', 'ASP.NET_SessionId=gpkufgrfzsk5abc0bc2v2v3e')]
        f = opener.open("https://urltest.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura="+fatura)
        file = open(faturanome, 'wb')
        file.write(f.read())
        file.close()
        print("file downloaded:"+str(ab)+" downloaded!")
    except:
        pass
```

Why is this so slow? The remote server is very fast too. Is there some way to get better results? Maybe putting several files in the queue? Like I said, we are still learning. We just want to find a way the script makes several quests at once to get several files at once, instead of one at a time.

So this is what I wrote after hours.. but doesnt work

Well, here we go.

What am I doing wrong ? I am giving my best, but I never used threading before. Hey @KlausD, check it and let me know what am I doing wrong ? it is a website that requir cookies. Also it need to load the ul and turn to pdf.

check my code try

```
import os
import threading
import urllib.request,string,random

from queue import Queue

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class Downloader(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, queue):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):

        while True:

            url = self.queue.get()


            self.download_file(url)


            self.queue.task_done()

    def download_file(self, url):

        faturanum = 20184009433300
        ab = ab + 1
        handle = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        a = id_generator() + ".pdf"
        faturanum = faturanum - 1
        fatura = str(faturanum)
        faturanome = fatura + ".pdf"
        handle.addheaders = [('Cookie', 'ASP.NET_SessionId=v5x4k1m44saix1f5hpybf2qu')]
        fname = os.path.basename(url)
        with open(fname, "wb") as f:
            while True:
                chunk = handle.read(1024)
                if not chunk: break
                f.write(chunk)

def main(urls):

    queue = Queue()


    for i in range(5):
        t = Downloader(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()


    for url in urls:
        queue.put(url)


    queue.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ["https://sitetest.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura="+fatura"]
    main(urls)
```

what is wrong THis is my best.. believe I am not sleeping to make it working

Comment: You are executing all requests in a loop, one after the other. You have to run multiple tasks at the same time. Check the docs of the threading package from the standard lib to see how.

Comment: would you mind to show me a solution using my script ? I did hear about threading package., but I honestly dont have ideia to how include multiple tasks at this code.

Comment: 4 minutes is an unbelievably great time for reading the docs. Please show some effort in solving the problem.

Comment: @KlausD.I honestly had a hard time to make this small single loop.I have no ideia of how to improve the code, making it to request mulltiple tasks at the same time. I am starting in python.

Comment: Could you gives a real website? And what is the executed code, you gave 2 codes.. If it's the first one I can try an heuristic solution: Remove the big dirty `try` / `except` on the whole `while` and I'm almost sure you will see 90% of your tries just failed (and that takes time to fails)

Comment: Sure, I could to give ithe url, bu you will need to get a new cookies from there before and inject in the script. The first code is working ... but it is real slow. THis is the reason I want to make a multiple thread... the first code rn very slow requesting one file per time... once the website is private, how could I share the url to you in private ?

Comment: another thing.. the URL is a link when opened, tit load a ,pdf file, understand ? it is not .pdf file itself... jus when opened, it load the pdf. hw can I talkwith you in private for security reasons ?

Comment: @Arount can  you help me with the second script that I posted ?? making it mult-tread.

Comment: @arount, i took off the try / except bt it keep slow. I believe the multi thread would solve my problem.. but I am not being able make the second code (multi-thread and queue) to work..someone, please!!